# Level set method : evolving from a single point fails

Tags: general-topology

I have been trying to understand more about the level set method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set_method

So I decided to simulate it in matlab starting from a simple circle as seen below
[image: Circle as the initial boundary]

[image: Result of initial circle boundary]

The above example was carried out without any issue.

However, I found that if the initial boundary is just a point with the same velocity distribution, then the level set function is always greater than 0. This makes the boundary extraction more difficult, as seen below,

[image: single point as the initial boundary][image: Evolution of the single point].

As clearly seen in the last figure, the level set function never passes through zero. Instead, the edge of the flat area represents the evolved boundary.

My question is:

1) What is causing this behaviour? I found that the same issue arises when the initial circle is too small (e.g. r=0.01).

2) Is there a way to 'naturally' set up the level set function so that negative value can be obtained for my single point case?

Thank you!

Comment: A downward transation allong the z axis should suffice.